# How to consume iOS Push notification in the app only

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, notifications, push

I am working on a app, where I need to send a push notification to the app to start processing data as needed.

How do I send a `push notification` to the device so that instead of showing the `alert message`, the `notification` is forwarded to the app - whether the app is in the foreground or background..

I did implement the delegate method :

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
```

however this is called only when the app is in the `foreground`. When the app is in the `background` the `notification` shows up on the `notification center`.

Please advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make this works you need to do few step:

- set background mode **remote-notification**
- implement `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:` method in app delegate
- and make sure push notification payload contains key `"content-available" : 1`

related docs:

[App States and Multitasking](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW20)

[Local and Push Notifications in Depth](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/WhatAreRemoteNotif.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH102-SW1)

Answer (score -1):

Is your application using a backend? An example would be Parse or another to store your data.

Parse, for example, allows you to add push notifications that can be customized and changed to get the most out of your application.